# Error when hiding page items then displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to hide an id within a page then display once all the javascript has loaded on the page. The javascript i'm using do display the content again is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#HomePage")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
   $('#HomePage').addClass('animated fadeIn'); 
   $("#CategoryPage")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
   $('#CategoryPage').addClass('animated fadeIn'); 
}
```

and the css i'm using is

```
#HomePage { visibility:hidden; }
#CategoryPage { visibility:hidden; }
```

and the html for the home page

```
<html>
 <body>
  <section id="HomePage" class="main-content">
   ...
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

and the html for the category page

```
<html>
 <body>
  <section id="CategoryPage" class="main-content">
   ...
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

This works fine for the home page - initially hides the div then displays but when i go to the category page for some reason the javascript isn't running. I am getting an error on both pages but i'm not sure if this would effect it as its still running on the home page - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: i've added the html i am using for both pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `#HomePage` exist on `#CategoryPage`? If I have understood your question correctly, it will try to look for `#HomePage` on the `#CategoryPage` and indeed declare it as `undefined`.

If you are using jQuery, the below should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#HomePage").css('visibility', 'visible');
      $('#HomePage').addClass('animated fadeIn');
      $("#CategoryPage").css('visibility', 'visible');
      $('#CategoryPage').addClass('animated fadeIn');
    }
```

Comment: no #HomePage only exists on the homepage and #CategoryPage on exists on the category page. Is the why the Category parts aren't running? is there a way around this?

Comment: @AlexMurray I'll edit my answer, just using jQuery's methods should fix it I think.

Answer (score 1):

Possibily your issue is when accessing the [0] index.  If '#HomePage' or '#CategoryPage' doesn't exist then it will throw an error as the first item in the array doesn't exist.  Try this instead...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#HomePage").css("visibility", "visible"); 
   $('#HomePage').addClass('animated fadeIn'); 
   $("#CategoryPage").css("visibility", "visible"); 
   $('#CategoryPage').addClass('animated fadeIn'); 
}
```

jQuery will apply css() to all items that match (or none if no matches).